# Gchart.php, dynamically filling dataset and legend

Tags: arrays, loops, gchart

I am trying to make a chart using gchart.php.

It takes the data in this format:

```
  $Chart->setLegend(array("blah", "bla2", "blah3"));
```

I have an array of forenames, the number of which could be anything, from 1 to 10 or higher.

I don't know the syntax of how I would go about splitting the array items with the " ", in between each of them, nor how to loop the syntax of (array("blah","blah") for the number of values I have in my array.

Quite a complicated question it seems, is this possible?

Comment: Never mind! I just worked it out. Incredibly simple.

Comment: $Chart->setLegend(array(forenamearray));